# How to get all data with a certain mode of payment?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to get all rows that have 'Card' as their mode of payment (`MOP`), inclusive of split MOPs. Say that this is the data:

| Receipt No. | MOP | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0001 | Cash | 100 |
| 0001 | GC | 70 |
| 0002 | Card | 500 |
| 0002 | Cash | 50 |
| 0003 | E-Wallet | 300 |
| 0004 | Card | 250 |
| 0005 | GC | 150 |
| 0006 | Card | 200 |
| 0006 | E-Wallet | 100 |
| 0007 | Card | 300 |

The outcome should be this:

| Receipt No. | MOP | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0002 | Card | 500 |
| 0002 | Cash | 50 |
| 0004 | Card | 250 |
| 0006 | Card | 200 |
| 0006 | E-Wallet | 100 |
| 0007 | Card | 300 |

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Exists logic comes to mind as one straightforward way:

```sql
SELECT t1.*
FROM yourTable t1
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM yourTable t2
              WHERE t2.ReceiptNo = t1.ReceiptNo AND t2.MOP = 'Card');
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use simple where close like this

```
select * from youtable where MOP = 'Card'
```